# Why could shader compiler decide to use ps_2_0 model?

Tags: visual-c++, hlsl

The shader compiler produces a warning for my shader saying

"error X5608: Compiled shader code uses too many arithmetic instruction slots (78). Max. allowed by the target (ps_2_0) is 64. Consider increasing optimization level to reduce instruction count."

However, I am using shader model 4:

[image]

What could make the compiler thinking that I am using ps_2_0? Am I missing some options/preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Shader Model but with Level 9_1 feature set, which is designed either to use Direct3D11 API on older cards that do not support "real" feature level 4.0, or embedded devices (read here, phones mostly).

So even if you can use Shader Model 4 syntax, your shader still needs to comply to the hardware capabilities (which, for level 9.1 is ps2.0).

See msdn blog about Feature Levels [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx)

If you know your target hardware works with feature level 4 (pretty much any laptop/desktop supports level 11 nowadays), you should use Shader Model 4 (/4_0) compiler option instead.